# Cómo programar una barra de navegación inferior?

Tags: android, android-studio

estoy tratando de disparar una funcion de un menu con BottomNavigationView  en un  activity, intente de esta forma... pero ningun Toast se disparo al presionar un item en mi menu no se donde esta mi error , alguien que me puede dar una mano Gracias.

```
 BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bottomNavigationView=(BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navfoot);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull  MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.menu:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"HOME",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.comanda:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Comanda",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.cuenta:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Cuenta",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ;
                    break;
                case R.id.ubicacion:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Ubicacion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });



}
```

mi archivo navigacion.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
        id="@+id/menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true"
    />
<item
        id="@+id/comanda"
        android:icon="@drawable/comanda"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
         android:enabled="true"
        android:title="Comanda" />
<item
        id="@+id/cuenta"
        android:icon="@drawable/cuenta"
         app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
         android:enabled="true"

        android:title="Cuenta"/>
<item
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:enabled="true"
    id="@+id/ubicacion"
    android:icon="@drawable/ubica"
    android:title="Ubicacion"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en tu xml falta el prefijo android al id:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    android:title="Home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:enabled="true"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/comanda"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:title="Comanda" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/cuenta"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:enabled="true"

    android:title="Cuenta"/>
<item
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/ubicacion"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp"
    android:title="Ubicacion"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes un error al definir los id de los elementos dentro del archivo navigacion.xml, los id se deben definir mediante `android:id`, ejemplo:

```
android:id="@+id/menu"
```

Ese es el problema por el cual no accedes a los elementos.

Me llama la atención que tu proyecto se subió a tu dispositivo ya que si definiste incorrectamente los ids, ¡tu proyecto no podría al menos construirse!

---

importante, el archivo `navigacion.xml` debe encontrarse dentro de `/res/menu/`
Este sería el archivo `navigacion.xml` corregido:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/comanda"
        android:icon="@drawable/comanda"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="Comanda" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cuenta"
        android:icon="@drawable/cuenta"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true"

        android:title="Cuenta"/>
    <item
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:id="@+id/ubicacion"
        android:icon="@drawable/ubica"
        android:title="Ubicacion"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys no me habia dado cuenta ...Funciona

Comment: @user62207 de hecho me llama la atención ya que si definiste incorrectamente los ids , no permitiría construir tu proyecto.